# Avahi / Samba on Snappy Core 16.04 ARM

Tags: 16.04, samba, ubuntu-core, avahi

Is there a way to install Avahi or Samba on Ubuntu Core 16.04 (RPI3) . I need to have my device discovered by name not by IP.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest you look at the short mDNS implementation used by snapweb; it relies on a Go module called github.com/presotto/go-mdns-sd:

- https://github.com/snapcore/snapweb/blob/master/avahi/avahi.go